# Why is Zirconium neutron transparent while Hafnium is such a neutron absorber?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, elements

Out of curiosity I've been researching about Hafnium and Zirconium. I'm curious as to why Hafnium (below Zirconium on the periodic table) is so often used in control rods, while Zirconium is transparent to neutrons.

What properties of these elements causes their respective effects? Is it a property of the element itself or how the lattice is composed?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is 'transparent', the various isotopes have in general lower total cross sections. You should check ENDF to get cross sections for the various neutron interactions.

Comment: There’s a great explanation for the pseudo-randomness of neutron-nuclear scattering lengths and cross sections in [Golub et al.](https://www.amazon.com/Ultra-Cold-Neutrons-R-Golub/dp/0750301155). At least, I learned it when I took a course from Golub and we used that book. Unfortunately I don’t have the book handy, and I don’t have time to do the argument justice from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a property of the element or isotope itself, as follows.

The number of protons and neutrons in a nucleus determines exactly how that nucleus will respond to being struck by an incoming neutron (which, because it is electrically neutral, almost completely ignores the electron cloud on its way in).

That response will also depend strongly on the kinetic energy of the neutron. For example, if there is a specific nuclear process which possesses an *activation energy*, then that process will not be elicited by a neutron which possesses less than that activation energy.

This means that one element or isotope may have a significant probability of interacting with a *thermal neutron* while another isotope might not- even though the inexperienced but dogmatic engineering program manager supervising your work might forcefully assert that both elements are bright and shiny in the bulk and differ only by one f-electron, and should therefore respond similarly.

Comment: I understand that a specific atom of zirconium may have a specific activation energy, but why does zirconium specifically have such a (high?) activation energy, and why it's sibling hafnium is apparently so low?

Comment: It has to do with the details of the quantized energy levels in the *nucleus* as functions of the proton/neutron ratio and of the nuclear radius. It turns out that the nucleus cannot be "fit" together in exactly such a way as to produce a smooth, continuous increase in binding energy as the radius gets progressively bigger-  because you cannot add fractions of protons or neutrons, and the radius of a nucleus is similarly not a continuous and smooth function of the number of nucleons in it.  These effect put discontinuous jumps and dips into the picture.

Comment: You should change all occurances of "element" in your answer to "isotope".  Different isotopes of the same element can have vastly different cross sections.

Comment: @NuclearFission, will do.